# Lotus Notes Rules "Mark as Read"?

Tags: lotus-notes

I have a rule set up in Lotus Notes to filter certain e-mails to a folder (Move to Folder). However, I can't figure out how to mark them as "Read" automatically. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Corey Sanders' answers fits the question better than that of tester. I suggest marking that answer as Solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an agent instead of a rule to mark specific mails as read.
More info in the Help file at "Automating Tasks Using Simple Agents".

Comment: Er...so...could you be a little more specific?  Perhaps an example. :)

Comment: An actual link would also be good.

Answer (score 14):

There are a number of examples on how to use agents to manage tasks in the Lotus Notes doc. See http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.notes85.help.doc/agt_automate_task_using_agent_c.html for the high-level topic that describes task automation using agents.

I created a task to mark messages in a particular folder as read after mail has arrived using the following steps.

1. Open the Mail application
2. Click "Create" -> "Agent" on the menu bar
3. Give the agent a name and description. In the Runtime section, pick "After new mail has arrived" in the "Action menu selection" drop list and set the "Target" drop list to the appropriate setting (EX| All unread documents).
4. In the right hand pane where code would be entered, choose "Simple action(s)" from the drop list that is current set to "Lotus Script".
5. In the left hand pane, choose "Document Selection".
6. At the bottom of the right hand pane, choose "Add Condition"
7. In the popup window, choose "In Folder" from the drop list and then pick the folder you are interested in. Click the "Add" button at the bottom of the window.
8. In the left hand pane, choose "Action"
9. In the right hand pane, click the "Add Action" button at the bottom of the pane.
10. In the popup window, choose "Mark Document Read" from the "Action" drop list and then click the "Add" button at the bottom of the window.
11. Choose File -> Save and then close the agent window.

Comment: I'm missing the "Add Condition" option that you mentioned in step 6. I'm running IBM Notes 9, not Lotus Notes 8.5, if that makes a difference.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare IBM Notes 9 here and I do have that "Add condition" button.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to go to Preferences > Basic Notes Client Configuration > Additional Options > Mark documents read when opened in preview pane.

IBM Notes 9