# Automatically mark emails as read in Lotus Notes without using an agent?

Tags: email, lotus-notes, email-filter

I would like to **automatically mark incoming E-Mails as read** if they have a certain word in the subject line.

Unfortunately I **can't use an agent** for that like suggested here: [Lotus Notes Rules "Mark as Read"?](https://superuser.com/questions/125787/lotus-notes-rules-mark-as-read) because I **don't have the right** to create agents in our companies System.

Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: judging by this: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd85forum.nsf/5f27803bba85d8e285256bf10054620d/f465394dd0f047d7852575b4004376f0?OpenDocument there isn't...

Comment: Thanks wmz. It seems that way as filters can't do this and agents are the suggested workaround in your find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible the way you want it.

The closest you could do is to set up a mail rule in your mail file. Have this move the mail to a folder out of your inbox.

More details on how mail rules works is here:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.notes.help.doc/DOC/H_USING_RULES_TO_FILTER_NEW_MESSAGES_STEPS.html

Comment: Thanks Simon. I'm already doing that. But I get a Mail notification from Notes everytime such an E-Mail is received nevertheless. That's the part that is still bugging me.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is apparently not any way to automatically mark e-mails read in Notes without an agent.  But here's some more info that *might* help.

If your Notes admin won't grant you the rights to create private agents, then he doesn't understand Notes security and shouldn't be an admin.  An agent that you write can only do what you already have the rights to do, so there's no reason to deny you the ability to create agents.  (Furthermore, he can deny you the ability to create LotusScript or Java agents, if that will make him feel better, but still allow you to create simple agents and Notes Formula Language agents.)

If you can explain this nicely to the admin (without speaking as though you have the attitude that he's a moron) he might be reasonable and allow you to create an agent to mark your mail as read.  Especially if you explain the purpose, and ask him to help you find some alternative way automatically mark certain mail read, if he resists.  Since he won't be able to find an alternate solution, and this is such a basic requirement of any decent mail client, he will hopefully realize how silly it is to resist your request.

If you have rights on your computer to install software, and in the end he still won't allow you this right, tell him you're going to install Outlook (that'll bug him) but instead install something like Thunderbird, which can presumably mark mail read through mail rules.  Thunderbird will have no problem making an IMAP connection to your Notes server.  Perhaps he'll be so annoyed at the idea of someone using Outlook to connect to "his" Notes server (people who are unreasonable about granting access also usually seem to be very possessive about the company resources they're supposed to support) that he'll relent and give you the ability to create your agent.

As a *very* last resort, you could try getting him to create the agent with his rights, and ask him to make it run on your behalf.  Read/Unread marks are *per-user* so I'm guessing it won't work if it runs normally under his rights.  But if it runs under his rights, but *on your behalf* (this is a setting in the agent's security tab) I think it will work.  Since I think the previous approaches are better, I've not tested this solution, and thus suggest it as a last resort.

Best of luck.